# Complex number and conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex number and $z^6=-16|z|^2$, how to prove that $|z|=0$ or $|z|=2$?

I tried to change $z$ into the form $|z|$ and I get $|z|^4=-16(e^{-6iθ})$

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: hint: take the absolute value of your equation.

Comment: |z| is not supposed to be the absolute value but modulus of z

Comment: I think Jonathan meant that the expression on the right is a Real number.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand, what do you mean by right , is it -16|z|?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with $$ z^6= -16|z|^2$$ .$z=0$ is an obvious solution. Now, for the nonzero solutions , write $z=e^{i\theta}$. Then $|z|^2= |re^{i\theta}|^2 =r^2 $ , and $z^6=r^6 e^{i6\theta}$. Now, set two sides equal to each other: $$r^6e^{i6\theta}=-16r^2 $$. Since $r\neq 0$ (since we already considered $0$ as a solution ), we cancel the $r's$ on both sides, to get: $r^4e^{i6\theta}=-16=-16(cos(\alpha)+isin(\alpha))=....$ (set real part equal to real part and imaginary part equal to imaginary part )

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot understand why |reiθ|^2=r^2?

Comment: In polar form, |re^{i\theta}|=r ; remember, polar form re^{i\theta} , $r$ is the modulus and  $\theta$ is the argument.

Comment: Oh, it's because r=|z|=|re^iθ|, right?

Comment: Exactly; you got it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|z|^{6}=|z^{6}|= |-16z^{2}|=|-16|\cdot |z^{2}| = 16|z|^{2}$. Hence, $|z|^{6} = 16|z|^{2}$ and so $|z|^{2}(|z|^{4}-16) = 0$. So, $|z|=0$ or $|z|=2$.

Comment: I can understand your statement if it is for real numbers. However, I am dealing with a complex number and its modulus. Are your expressions also valid for complex numbers? Sorry, I can figure out how is the difference between modulus and absolute value, can you tell me this?

Comment: @Slavica, these are just properties of the modulus. Let $z=re^{it}$. Then $|z^{6}| = |r^{6}||e^{6it}| = |r^{6}| = |r|^{6}$. Similarly, $|-16z^{2}| = |-16r^{2}e^{2it}| = |-16r^{2}| = 16|r|^{2}$. Since $r^{6} = 16r^{2}$, $|r| = 0$ or $|r| = 2$, but remember that $|z|=|r|$ and so $|z| = 0$ or $|z| = 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still cannot understand how could you get this |r6||e6it|=|r6|?

Comment: @Slavica, $|e^{6it}|=|\text{cos}(6t)+i\text{sin}(6t)|=\sqrt{\text{cos}^{2}(6t) + \text{sin}^2(6t)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$.